# Determining whether or not these spaces are convex

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

Consider  $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x| +y^2\leq 5\}$ and $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y\geq x^2,y\leq e^{-x^2}\}$. Determine whether or not these two are convex sets.

I have used the visual inspection method. For those using Mathematica these are:

> RegionPlot[Abs[x] + y^2 <= 5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]

and

> RegionPlot[y >= x^2 && y <= E^(-x^2), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

Now, upon inspection, it looks to me as though both spaces are convex - which is to say if I take two points $x$ and $y$ both inside the given spaces, then the straight line connecting these two points also is inside the space. But I would like some verification on it.

Comment: have you tried the definition of convexness?

Comment: I find it somewhat challenging to use the definition for this case.

Comment: @Tom83B can you kindly explain to us how you plan to use the definition of convexity here ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was just wondering. I tried solving
$$|tx_1+(1-t)x_2|+(ty_1+(1-t)y_2)^2\leq5$$
but no success so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed both sets are convex!

A convex function is necessarily quasi-convex, i.e the sub-level sets $\mathrm{lev}_{\le \alpha} f := \{z | f(z) \le \alpha\}$ are convex. What you have there are sub-level sets of convex functions or intersections of such. For example, $f: (x, y) \mapsto -y$ and $g : (x, y) \mapsto -e^{-x^2} + y$ are convex functions (for example, show that they're smooth with  positive semi-definite Hessians), and so 
$$\{(x, y) | x^2 \le y \le e^{-x^2}\} = \mathrm{lev}_{\le 0} f \cap \mathrm{lev}_{\le 0} g$$
is convex.

Similarly, $h: (x, y) \mapsto |x| + y^2$ is convex being the sum of convex functions (spoiler: $(x, y) \mapsto |x|$ is convex by the triangle inequality, whilst $(x, y) \mapsto y^2$ is convex by a simple Hessian test, once again). Thus 
$$\{(x, y)||x| + y^2 \le 5\} = \mathrm{lev}_{\le 5} h$$
is convex.